# Generate Unique Combinations of Integers

Tags: math, combinations, pseudocode

I am looking for help with pseudo code (*unless you are a user of Game Maker 8.0 by Mark Overmars and know the GML equivalent of what I need*) for how to generate a list / array of unique combinations of a set of X number of integers which size is variable. It can be 1-5 or 1-1000.

**For example:**

IntegerList{1,2,3,4}

1,2

1,3

1,4

2,3

2,4

3,4

I feel like the math behind this is simple I just cant seem to wrap my head around it after checking multiple sources on how to do it in languages such as C++ and Java. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are not many details in the question, I assume:

- Your input is a natural number n and the resulting array contains all natural numbers from `1` to `n`.
- The expected output given by the combinations above, resembles a symmetric relation, i. e. in your case `[1, 2]` is considered the same as `[2, 1]`.
- Combinations `[x, x]` are excluded.
- There are only combinations with 2 elements.
- There is no `List<>` datatype or dynamic array, so the array length has to be known before creating the array.
- The number of elements in your result is therefore the binomial coefficient `m = n over 2 = n! / (2! * (n - 2)!)` (which is `4! / (2! * (4 - 2)!) = 24 / 4 = 6` in your example) with `!` being the factorial.

First, initializing the array with the first n natural numbers should be quite easy using the array element index. However, the index is a property of the array elements, so you don't need to initialize them in the first place.

You need 2 nested loops processing the array. The outer loop ranges `i` from `1` to `n - 1`, the inner loop ranges `j` from `2` to `n`. If your indexes start from `0` instead of `1`, you have to take this into consideration for the loop limits. Now, you only need to fill your target array with the combinations `[i, j]`. To find the correct index in your target array, you should use a third counter variable, initialized with the first index and incremented at the end of the inner loop.

I agree, the math behind is not that hard and I think this explanation should suffice to develop the corresponding code yourself.

Comment: Thank you, that is spot on what I was trying to wrap my head around. You're assumptions on the conditions of the data and the input were correct and I apologize for not being concise enough to start with.

Comment: Glad it helped :)