# How to compare 1,000 images using the available memory efficiently

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management, comparison, memory-efficient

This is a tough problem. I have around 1,000 images stored in my disk, and I want to find images that are similar to each other by comparing them in pairs. So I have to do around [1,000 * 999 / 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958633/generate-unique-combinations-of-integers) = 499,500 comparisons (the property of "being similar" is not transitive). My problem is not related with how to compare the images, but with how to manage efficiently the memory of my machine during the comparisons. I have already implemented the comparison function:

```
static bool AreSimilar(ImageInfo x, ImageInfo y)
{
    // Logic
}
```

...where `ImageInfo` is a class that holds the information for one image:

```
class ImageInfo : IDisposable
{
    public string Path { get; init; }
    public System.Drawing.Image Image { get; init; }
    public void Dispose() => Image.Dispose();
}
```

Ideally I would like to load all 1,000 images in memory, and then do a nested loop and invoke the `AreSimilar` method for each pair, but the memory needed for loading all of them at once exceeds by far the available memory of my machine. The image files are quite large, and their size varies considerably (most of them have sizes between 5 and 50 MB). The available RAM is 2 GB, so I can't have more than ~80 images loaded at the same time. Loading an image form the disk is quite slow. It is actually a lot slower to load two images from the disk, than to compare them
and find whether they are similar.

My question is how can I implement a method that will have the responsibility of loading/unloading the images from the disk, and yielding them in pairs, while taking advantage of all the available memory, but without exceeding the memory limit. Here is the signature of the method that I am trying to implement:

```
static IEnumerable<(TItem, TItem)> GetPairs<TSource, TItem>(
    IReadOnlyList<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, long> sizeSelector,
    Func<TSource, TItem> itemLoader,
    long maxConcurrentSize) where TItem : IDisposable;
```

The `TSource` will be the path of the file, and the `TItem` will be an `ImageInfo`. I am intending to use it like this:

```
string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Images", "*.jpg");
var pairs = GetPairs(paths,
    path => new FileInfo(path).Length,
    path => new ImageInfo() { Path = path, Image = Image.FromFile(path) },
    2_000_000_000);
foreach (var (x, y) in pairs)
{
    if (AreSimilar(x, y))
        Console.WriteLine($"{x.Path} and {y.Path} are similar!");
}
```

I am currently out of ideas of how to implement this method. It looks like a serious undertaking. All I have right now is the simple version below, that loads the images in pairs and ignores the `sizeSelector` and `maxConcurrentSize` parameters:

```
static IEnumerable<(TItem, TItem)> GetPairs<TSource, TItem>(
    IReadOnlyList<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, long> sizeSelector,
    Func<TSource, TItem> itemLoader,
    long maxConcurrentSize) where TItem : IDisposable
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        using var first = itemLoader(source[i]);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < source.Count; j++)
        {
            using var second = itemLoader(source[j]);
            yield return (first, second);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously the performance is terrible, since each image is loaded ~500 times on average.

Comment: I don't see what your problem is. You've written GetPairs already, and you clearly have the understanding to check `if((sizeSelector(first)+sizeSelector(second)) > maxConcurrentSize) HandleOverflow();`. So what is the problem? Are you still running out of memory?

Comment: As an aside, this looks like an overuse of generics. Why make `TSource` and `TItem` generic?

Comment: To solve the slow loading of images and memory limit constraints, you may consider creating an image buffer using async. Then as  you dequeue images from the buffer for comparison you asynchronously keep queuing more images into it. This way the compare logic is never waiting for images to load, the compare logic just requests the next image from the buffer. And only enough images that can be handled by memory are loaded at any given time.

Comment: @NigelBess the simple `GetPairs` implementation that I've posted in the question doesn't make efficient use of the available memory. Only two images are loaded concurrently at a time. I am searching for a more efficient implementation that will load more images concurrently, minimizing this way the total number of image-loadings. The theoretical minimum is 1,000 (with infinite memory available). My current implementation does around 500,000. My goal is to drop this number to 50,000 or less. As for the generics, it might not be YAGNI-compatible, but I like general solutions to problems.

Comment: @quaabaam keep in mind that I don't just want to do something with each image. I want to do something with each **pair** of images. And this requires that both images must be loaded while I am processing a pair. I don't see how my pairing problem can be solved by using an asynchronous buffer. I you have a specific idea about it, please consider positing it as an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how your comparison algorithm works, but is it possible to create some sort of abstract representation of your images that is less complex than the images themselves, and then compare pairs of *that*?

Comment: @Jonathan possibly yes. The focus of this question though is on the memory management problem. So the assumption is that the image-comparison algorithm can not be optimized any further, and the only thing that can be improved is the memory management.

Comment: Speed is relative. A fast way to keep all of the images readily available would be to use a [MemoryMappedFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) to read your images. However, the cost of combining all of the images into one or many "index" files that you can use would need to write all of the images into would probably be much slower than simply reading them from disk two images at a time. It depends on whether the "indexing" stage is acceptable for your use case.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I have no experience working with `MemoryMappedFile`s, but my understanding is that if I try to create a `MemoryMappedFile` for each of my images I will run out of memory. The size of all images combined is way larger than the available memory in my machine. But if you have a concrete idea of how I could use `MemoryMappedFile`s to solve my problem, please consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: Actually, no `MemoryMappedFile` is for working with *virutual memory*, so the entire file is not loaded in memory at once, but it gives you fast access to the data within the file. I haven't attempted to use images for this, so I am not sure how well this will work out.

Comment: I understand the problem now. You are looking for an algorithm that leads to a single loading of each image if the available memory is large enough, and makes use of all available memory. It's a tricky one. I'll think about it and let you know if I come up with something. It seems like the first step is to divide up the images into subsets that can be loaded at once, but then the tricky part is the inter-subset comparison

Comment: I recommend solving the case where the images are all the same size first. That is a difficult enough problem already, so I would worry about varying image sizes later.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias to me loading and comparing are two separate problems. The buffer isn't concerned with how the images are compared or how many images you pull from it at a time. You could pull 1 or 2 images from the buffer, or more. The buffer's only responsibility is to ensure it has images already loaded when they are asked for and that it continually buffers more images from disk. This doesn't solve your compare problem but it does solve the problem of the compare process having to wait for images to load.

Comment: Are you worried about time complexity? Or is this a pure memory optimization?

Comment: @NigelBess the focus is on the memory optimization. Time complexity is a secondary consideration, and for the purpose of answering this question it can be safely ignored.

Comment: Create some kind of custom "hashing" algorithm to reduce the images down to something much smaller. However, the difference here is that _want_ your hash values to have collisions, such that two images that are similar will always have the same hash. Then you only need to load each image once to compute its hash. Afterwards you can compare all the hashes, which should easily fit in memory. Additionally, each comparison operation will itself will be _MUCH_ faster.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks for the suggestion, but lowering the quality of the comparison is not an option. It is required that the images are compared in their original size. Also hash-based comparison implies that the property of "being similar" is transitive, which is not the case. If A is similar to B and B is similar to C, it doesn't follow that A is similar to C.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn OP stated that we can assume ImageInfo is already reduced as much as possible to make the comparison viable

Comment: Thinking about this problem a little more, I think you want to generate a kind of super-permutation. You have 1,000 distinct items, and you want to generate a sequence such that every pair of 2 items appear within 80 positions, at least once. That way you evict one image as you load another, in the order of the permutation, then perform comparisons against the other 79 images you have cached in memory. Generating an optimal sequence sounds like a graph theory problem.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman the number 80 is just an approximation of how many images I can load concurrently, based on their average size. But the actual limit is imposed by their actual size, that varies considerably. As some moment I might be able to load 200 small images concurrently, or the available memory might run out after loading only 50 large images. This complication makes the problem even more difficult! I am not asking for the optimal solution, because I understand that it might be a NP-hard problem. I will be satisfied with a simple algorithm that performs reasonably well.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if C# is the best tool here. There's probably a virtual memory trick you could use to push the problem down to the OS to solve. Then just try to use some "cache oblivious" approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to come up with a compact algorithm that solves this quite difficult problem. The algorithm maintains 5 pieces of information as state:

1. A list with the items that are currently loaded.
2. The total size of the currently loaded items.
3. A queue with the items that are not currently loaded.
4. An array containing the number of pairs that are remaining for each item.
5. A [`BitArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray) storing whether any particular pair has been emitted.

The algorithm moves items between the two collections `loaded` and `unloaded`, loads and unloads items in respect to the `maxConcurrentSize` policy, yields as many pairs from the `loaded` list is possible, and continues until both collections are empty. At that point all possible pairs are expected to be emitted, provided that the algorithm is correct.

```
public static IEnumerable<(TItem, TItem)> GetPairs<TSource, TItem>(
    IReadOnlyList<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, long> sizeSelector,
    Func<TSource, TItem> itemLoader,
    long maxConcurrentSize) where TItem : IDisposable
{
    List<(int Index, TItem Item, long Size)> loaded = new();
    try
    {
        long loadedSumSize = 0L;
        Queue<int> unloaded = new(Enumerable.Range(0, source.Count));
        int[] pending = new int[source.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < pending.Length; i++) pending[i] = source.Count - 1;
        BitArray emittedPairs = new(checked(source.Count * (source.Count - 1) >> 1));
        while (unloaded.Count > 0)
        {
            // Select the next item to load, in FIFO order.
            int indexToLoad = unloaded.Dequeue();
            long sizeToLoad = Math.Max(0L, sizeSelector(source[indexToLoad]));

            // Unload already loaded items until there is enough space for the
            // new item, in LIFO order.
            while (loaded.Count > 1 && loadedSumSize + sizeToLoad > maxConcurrentSize)
            {
                var toUnload = loaded[loaded.Count - 1];
                loaded.RemoveAt(loaded.Count - 1);
                toUnload.Item.Dispose();
                unloaded.Enqueue(toUnload.Index);
                loadedSumSize -= toUnload.Size;
            }

            // Load the new item.
            var itemToLoad = itemLoader(source[indexToLoad]);
            loaded.Add((indexToLoad, itemToLoad, sizeToLoad));
            checked { loadedSumSize += sizeToLoad; }
            var justLoaded = loaded[loaded.Count - 1];

            // Yield pairs constituted of the new item with all already loaded items.
            for (int i = 0; i < loaded.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                var existing = loaded[i];
                Debug.Assert(existing.Index != justLoaded.Index);

                // Switch the order in case the pair is not in the correct order.
                var (x, y) = existing.Index < justLoaded.Index ?
                    (existing, justLoaded) : (justLoaded, existing);

                // Emit the pair if it's not already emitted.
                int emittedIndex = (y.Index * (y.Index - 1) >> 1) + x.Index;
                if (emittedPairs[emittedIndex]) continue;
                yield return (x.Item, y.Item);
                emittedPairs[emittedIndex] = true;
                pending[x.Index]--;
                pending[y.Index]--;
            }

            // Unload all items that are completed.
            for (int i = loaded.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var (index, item, size) = loaded[i];
                if (pending[index] > 0) continue;
                Debug.Assert(pending[index] == 0);
                loaded.RemoveAt(i);
                item.Dispose();
                loadedSumSize -= size;
            }
        }

        // If the algorithm is correct, these final assertions should never fail.
        Debug.Assert(loaded.Count == 0);
        Debug.Assert(loadedSumSize == 0L);
        Debug.Assert(pending.All(n => n == 0));
        Debug.Assert(emittedPairs.Cast<bool>().All(b => b));
    }
    finally
    {
        // Ensure that in case the enumerable is enumerated only partially,
        // all currently loaded items will be disposed.
        foreach (var entry in loaded) entry.Item.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I measured the efficiency of this implementation by writing a simulation of the original problem:

1. 1,000 files, each having size between 5 and 50 MB.
2. `maxConcurrentSize` equal to 2 GB.

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToArray();
var random = new Random(0);
var sizes = source.ToDictionary(x => x,
    _ => (long)random.Next(5_000_000, 50_000_000));
int loaderInvokedCount = 0;
var query = GetPairs(source, x => sizes[x], x =>
{
    loaderInvokedCount++;
    return new MemoryStream();
}, 2_000_000_000);
var emittedPairsCount = query.Count();
Console.WriteLine($"Emitted {emittedPairsCount:#,0} pairs");
Console.WriteLine($"Loader invoked {loaderInvokedCount:#,0} times");
```

Output:

```
Emitted 499,500 pairs
Loader invoked 7,682 times
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L3yKmx).

The naive implementation presented as part of the question invokes the loader 500,500 times for the same input, which is 65 times more compared to this implementation. Achieving a 98,5% discount is a quite satisfactory outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works for your problem, with an included unit test. Unfortunately it performs poorly in the case where only small numbers of images are able to load at a time, resulting in at worst 2x the number of loads as your proposed solution. However, when a large number of images can be loaded at a time, this algorithm begins to outperform your algorithm, limiting towards 1 load per image as the allowable memory size increases.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTest;


[TestClass]
public class TestComparison
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        const int imageCount = 10;
        var (totalLoads, max, pairs) = RunTest(1, 5, 1000, imageCount);
        Assert.AreEqual(10, totalLoads);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, max);

        (_, max, var pairs2) = RunTest(5, 5, 12, imageCount);
        Assert.AreEqual(9, max);

        var expectedPairs = (imageCount - 1) * imageCount / 2;
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedPairs, pairs.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedPairs, pairs2.Count);
    }

    private (int totalLoads, int maxLoads, List<(ImageInfo, ImageInfo)> pairs) RunTest(int minImageSize, int maxImageSize, long memorySize, int imageCount)
    {
        var images = GenerateImages(imageCount, minImageSize, maxImageSize);
        var paths = images.Keys.ToList();
        var imageLoadCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        var pairs = GetPairs(paths,p=>images[p].Size,LoadImage,memorySize).ToList();

        var totalLoads = imageLoadCounts.Values.Sum();
        var maxLoad = imageLoadCounts.Values.Max();
        return new(totalLoads, maxLoad,pairs);

        ImageInfo LoadImage(string path)
        {
            if (!imageLoadCounts.TryGetValue(path, out int count))
            {
                count = 0;
            }

            count++;
            imageLoadCounts[path] = count;

            return images[path];
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, ImageInfo> GenerateImages(int imageCount, int minImageSize, int maxImageSize)
    {
        var images = new Dictionary<string,ImageInfo>();
        for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
        {
            images[RandomString()] = new() { Value = _random.NextSingle(), Size = _random.Next(minImageSize, maxImageSize) };
        }

        return images;
    }

    class ImageInfo:IDisposable
    {
        public int Size { get; set; }
        public float Value { get; set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }

    private static readonly Random _random = new();


    static string RandomString()
    {
        const int length = 10;
        var str = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            str += (char)_random.Next(65, 90);
        }

        return str;
    }



    static bool AreSimilar(ImageInfo x, ImageInfo y) => Math.Abs(y.Value-x.Value)<.1f;
    record Comparison<T>(T Path1, T Path2)
    {
        public bool Contains(T path) => Path1.Equals(path) || Path2.Equals(path);


        public T Other(T path)
        {
            if (Path1.Equals(path)) return Path2;
            if (Path2.Equals(path)) return Path1;
            throw new Exception("invalid path");
        }

        public bool IsEquivalentTo(Comparison<T> other) => (other.Path1.Equals(Path1) && other.Path2.Equals(Path2)) ||
                                                           (other.Path2.Equals(Path1) && other.Path1.Equals(Path2));
    }
    static IEnumerable<(TItem, TItem)> GetPairs<TSource, TItem>(
        IReadOnlyList<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, long> sizeSelector,
        Func<TSource, TItem> itemLoader,
        long maxConcurrentSize) where TItem : IDisposable
    {

        var itemCount = source.Count;
        var comparisons = new List<Comparison<TSource>>(itemCount * itemCount / 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < itemCount; j++)
            {
                comparisons.Add(new(source[i], source[j]));
            }
        }

        return GetPairs(comparisons,sizeSelector,itemLoader,maxConcurrentSize);
    }

    static IEnumerable<(TItem, TItem)> GetPairs<TSource,TItem>(List<Comparison<TSource>> remainingComparisons,
        Func<TSource, long> sizeSelector,
        Func<TSource, TItem> itemLoader,
        long maxConcurrentSize) where TItem:IDisposable
    {
        if(!remainingComparisons.Any()) yield break;
        var images = LoadImages(remainingComparisons,sizeSelector,itemLoader,maxConcurrentSize);//load as many images as possible from the remaining comparisons
        var imageCount = images.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < imageCount - 1; i++)
        {
            var (path1, image1) = images[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < imageCount; j++)
            {
                var (path2, image2) = images[j];
                yield return new(image1, image2);
                var comparison = new Comparison<TSource>(path1, path2);
                remainingComparisons.RemoveAll(c => c.IsEquivalentTo(comparison));
            }
        }

        //dispose
        foreach (var image in images.Select(i => i.Image))
        {
            image.Dispose();
        }

        images = null;//allow GC
        foreach (var pair in GetPairs(remainingComparisons,sizeSelector,itemLoader,maxConcurrentSize))
        {
            yield return pair;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads as many images into memory as possible from the remaining comparison list
    /// </summary>
    static List<(TSource Path, TITem Image)> LoadImages<TSource,TITem>(List<Comparison<TSource>> remainingComparisons, Func<TSource, long> sizeSelector,
        Func<TSource, TITem> itemLoader,
        long maxConcurrentSize)
    {
        var availableMemory = maxConcurrentSize;
        remainingComparisons = remainingComparisons.ToList();//copy the list so we can alter it in local scope
        var loadedImages = new List<(TSource Path, TITem Image)>();
        if (!TryGetSeed(out var seed)) throw new Exception("One of the images is too large to load into memory");
        while (remainingComparisons.Any())
        {
            if (!remainingComparisons.TryGetFirst(c => c.Contains(seed),out var comparison ))
            {
                if (!TryGetSeed(out seed)) break;
                continue;
            }

            var other = comparison.Other(seed);
            remainingComparisons.Remove(comparison);
            if (!TryLoad(other)) break;

        }

        return loadedImages;

        bool TryLoad(TSource path)
        {
            var fileSize = sizeSelector(path);
            if (fileSize > availableMemory) return false;
            loadedImages.Add(new(path, itemLoader(path)));
            availableMemory -= fileSize;
            return true;
        }

        bool TryGetSeed(out TSource seed)
        {
            //first, remove any comparisons that are relevant to the current loaded list
            var loadedImageCount = loadedImages.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < loadedImageCount-1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < loadedImageCount; j++)
                {
                    var localComparison = new Comparison<TSource>(loadedImages[i].Path, loadedImages[j].Path);
                    remainingComparisons.RemoveAll(c => c.IsEquivalentTo(localComparison));
                }
            }

            if (!remainingComparisons.TryGetFirst(out var firstRemaining))
            {
                seed = default;
                return false;
            }

            seed = firstRemaining.Path1;
            return TryLoad(seed);
        }

  


    }
}
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool TryGetFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, out T value) =>
        items.TryGetFirst(t => true, out value);
    public static bool TryGetFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> condition, out T value)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (condition(item))
            {
                value = item;
                return true;
            }
        }
        value = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```

For the sake of answering your question, time complexity was ignored. The current implementation of `TryGetSeed` makes the time complexity O(N^3) but this can easily be improved. I suspect the same algorithm could be written in O(N^2) time, which is the best possible time complexity for this problem.

Comment: Thanks @NigelBess for the answer! I could test immediately your implementation and validate its correctness if it had the generic signature specified in the question (`GetPairs<TSource, TItem>(...`), because I have already a test harness for it. Now I'll have first to convert your non generic implementation to a generic one, and then test it. Hopefully I'll find the time to do it soon.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I guarantee that the code will not work because I haven't tested it. The purpose is to explain an algorithm that you can use.

Comment: Thanks Nigel for the update. I ran the code and I can confirm that your tests are passing. I still have to find the time and convert it from non-generic to generic, in order to test it with my own test harness, which is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fO4ZuK) btw.

Comment: Hi Nigel! I tested your method, and I'm getting some duplicate pairs. For example with 6 items of size 1, and `maxConcurrentSize = 3` I get these pairs (ordered): (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 5), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 2), (6, 4). [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CwpNrM). Also I am getting a `StackOverflowException` when the `maxConcurrentSize` is very small. [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U4Kx8X).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes I expect this algorithm to have duplicate pairs (up to 2x of each pair) until the memory becomes sufficiently large. This is what I described in the opening paragraph. The point is to make sure it finds all the pairs, so that you can complete all the comparisons.

If `maxConcurrentSize` is too small to load any two images, of course there will be an Exception, do you somehow expect otherwise?

Comment: Nigel yep, you are right. Before starting the calculation, an important validation step would be to ensure that the 2 largest images combined do non exceed the available memory. Which is trivial to do. As for the duplicate pairs, they can be easily filtered out by using a `HashSet<(TItem, TItem)>`. So your answer solves the hard part of the problem, and I can accept it. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias FYI the duplicate pairs will still be loaded to memory twice

Comment: Ouch! That's a flaw. Is there any easy way to fix it?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias No, you would have to write a different algorithm, and there very well might not be one. If you look into how my algorithm works you will see why. But as I mentioned, this is only a problem when memory is very small, and in absolute worst case leads to each image being loaded 2x as often as it needs to be.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Examine the case where we have 10 images of size 1. Your algorithm requires 45 loads regardless of how much memory is available. On the other hand, my algorithm requires 90, 62, 48, 37, 24, 32, 26, 10, 10 ... loads as memory increases from 2, 3, 4, ...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias so as soon as enough memory becomes available to load about 5 of the images at once, my algorithm will start to outperform yours.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias you could add a special clause: `if(maxLoadableImages==2) use your algorithm;`. Then the number of total loads becomes 45, 62, 48, 37, 24, 32, 26, 10, 10 ..., which is really not bad at all

Comment: In the case where there are 50 images of size 1, the total number of loads looks like this as memory size goes from 2 to 50:

2450, 1802, 1460, 1279, 1272, 982, 1232, 834, 790, 934, 732, 778, 655, 633, 693, 726, 504, 527, 500, 546, 523, 593, 609, 657, 364, 402, 420, 457, 480, 516, 544, 579, 612, 452, 468, 495, 520, 426, 440, 379, 396, 352, 322, 300, 260, 232, 192, 146, 50

Comment: Unfortunately having available memory that is a small fraction of the total size of all the images, is exactly the scenario that I am targeting. The total size of my images is around 25 GB, and the available memory in my machine is 2 GB. Running a simulation with 1,000 images is not currently possible because of the time complexity, but with 100 images and the same ratio your algorithm results to 25% less loadings compared to my naive implementation ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PiEWD9)), which is quite disappointing to be honest!

Comment: A simple 'thank you' would've sufficed. You should realize I spent a few hours making this algorithm for no reason other than to help you out. Good luck on your problem and on writing your own algorithm!

Comment: Sure Nigel, I am thankful for your effort. Please note that I've given clues in the question that the problem is hard. It's not the kind of problem that is fun to solve. Solving it feels more like work than entertainment. :-)